# git init shows fatal: unable to access

Tags: git

I'm new to git, and while creating new repository with command:

```
git init
```

Im getting an error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'C:\Users\mubee;C:\Program Files (x86)\graphviz-2.40.1;/.config/git/config': Invalid argument
```

I have no idea how to resolve this, i have installed a 'python-git-package'. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are adminstrator of yhis computer?

Answer (score 0):

In order for git to be able to execute your `git init`, the target repo must be writable. I'm guessing you don't have the right permissions on this repository.

Try running your shell as administrator.

**EDIT**

As recommend by @eis locating your project in a writable environment would be optimal here. Don't use `Program Files (x86)` as a location.

Comment: or try using repository folders which you do have access. Running it as an administrator will likely introduce other difficulties if you're not the only user of the computer. would you store your ssh keys also on the admin account?